# Formula in expression field for a column

Tags: c#

I used an expression for one of my columns in a data table like this:

```
(col2-col1)*col3/100
```

col2 and col1 are bigint and col3 is smallint

But, finally as a result it returns a number that is not exactly what it must be.

For example:

(100000-0)*10/100 will return 9999

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a rounding issue. Can you switch to a decimal type (rather than int variants) with explicit precision?